# Pipelined copy-item doesnt work after a file is renamed

Tags: powershell, pipeline, copy-item

I am quite new to PowerShell.

I have created a PowerShell script which identifies a specific Mp3 file out of a large number of very similar files in one folder based on certain criteria:

1. Is the most recent file created
2. It is an MP3 file
3. It has a certain character set in the file name.

The file is then renamed to today's date and adds some other text to the file name:

```
$AudioDir = "\\Server\Audio\"

$MediaDir = "\\Server2\Media\"

$LatestMP3 = Get-ChildItem -Path $AudioDir "*NEW.MP3" | Sort-Object CreationTime | Select-Object -Last 1

Get-ChildItem -path $AudioDir $LatestMP3 |Rename-Item -newname {(GET-DATE).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + " NewAUDIO.mp3"}
```

This part works perfectly but the next step does not. I want to copy that renamed file to another folder on another server (`$MediaDir = "\\Server2\Media\"`)

I am trying a pipe:

```
Get-ChildItem -path $AudioDir $LatestMP3 |Rename-Item -newname {(GET-DATE).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + " NewAUDIO.mp3"} | Copy-Item -destination $MediaDir
```

There is no error, the file renames as expected but the `Copy-Item -destination $MediaDir` does nothing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Just to clarify: `Copy-Item` step works in Powershell ISE, but not in CMD or Task Scheduler?
For starters, try adding `-Verbose` and `-ErrorAction Stop` to `Copy-Item` - this should give you more verbose output.

Comment: Hi, sorry the title was misleading which I have edited now. The issue is copy-item -destination $MediaDir doesn't work after the file is renamed

Answer (score 4):

By default, the `Rename-Item` CmdLet doesn't return anything. You'll have to force it to in a pipe. Use the `PassThru` parameter when in the pipe and it should copy just fine.

```
Get-ChildItem -path $AudioDir $LatestMP3 |Rename-Item -newname {(GET-DATE).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + " NewAUDIO.mp3"} -PassThru | Copy-Item -destination $MediaDir
```

Comment: Thanks so much SomeShinyObject! That worked perfectly and I understand why too. I'm getting better at this by learning every day!

Comment: Glad to help. If I helped answer your question, be sure to click the check so it shows the question was answered.